# Matching rows from one dataset to a reference dataset (R)

Tags: r

I have a question.
Let's say I have two data frames.

```
values    <-   data.frame(x = rnorm(10000), y = rnorm(10000), matches = 0)
reference <-   data.frame(a = rnorm(10000), b = rnorm(10000))
```

For each row in “values”, I would like to know how many matches there are in the “reference” dataset within a defined range.

```
system.time(

for (i in 1:nrow(values))
{  
# defining valid range    
x1 <- values$x[i] - 0.1 
x2 <- values$x[i] + 0.1
y1 <- values$y[i] - 0.2
y2 <- values$y[i] + 0.2

#matching values versus reference dataset
values$matches[i] <- nrow(reference[reference$a %between% c(x1,x2) & reference$b %between% c(y1,y2),])
}

)


user  system elapsed 
9.91    0.03    9.94
```

The example above is functional, but for large datasets it takes ages. 
Can maybe this be done with data.table?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It appears you are already using `data.table`, as "%between%" is not an operator in base R. You may want to add the `data.table` tag to your question.

Comment: What is the `dim` of your actual data? Does always `nrow(values) == nrow(reference)`? Are there 2 columns or you might need `reference$a between c(x1, x2) & reference$b between c(y1, y2) & reference$c between c(zi, z2) & ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `data.table` method:

```
# set of data.tables
values    <-   setDT(data.frame(x = rnorm(10000), y = rnorm(10000), matches = 0))
reference <-   setDT(data.frame(a = rnorm(10000), b = rnorm(10000)))
# calculate sum of ranges, initialize matches variable as integer for speed
values[, matches := integer(nrow(values))]

values[, matches := sum(reference$a %between% c(x-0.1, x+0.1) * 
                        reference$b %between% c(y-0.2, y+0.2)), by=rownames(values)]
```

It's probably faster than what you have, though there is likely a faster method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using dplyr's rowwise().
If the "defined range" is symetric you can improve performance by checking only two conditions:

```
count_matches <- function(x, y) {
    sum(abs(reference$a - x) <= 0.1 & abs(reference$b - y) <= 0.2)
}

library(dplyr)
values %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(matches = count_matches(x, y))
```